# How does one represent MongoDB GeoJSON fields in a Mongoose Schema?

Tags: mongodb, schema, mongoose, geospatial, geojson

MongoDB 2.4 allows the use of [GeoJSON](http://www.geojson.org/geojson-spec.html) objects and a slew of [neat functions and indexes](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/applications/2dsphere/) that I'd like to use.

It expects GeoJSON objects to be stored in the format like:

```
loc: {
  type: 'Polygon',
  coordinates: [[[-180.0, 10.0], [20.0, 90.0], [180.0, -5.0], [-30.0, -90.0]]]
}
```

So in Mongoose one would think the schema would be defined like:

```
loc: { type: 'string', coordinates: [[['number']]] }
```

But this present two problems:

1. having a field called "type" screws up Mongoose's schema parsing
   because it allows defining fields in the form field: { type: ,
   index: } etc.
2. Mongoose does not like nested arrays.

One way to overcome this is to simply use `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed`, however I feel that there has got to be a better way!

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You must used Mixed to represent arrays of arrays. There is an [open ticket](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/issues/1361) to support this in the future.

@nevi_me is correct, you must declare the `type` property as he described.

Here's a gist: https://gist.github.com/aheckmann/5241574

See the mongoose tests here for more ideas: https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/blob/master/test/model.querying.test.js#L1931

Comment: Thanks! It would be nice to see an explanation of this in the Mongoose docs.

Answer (score 49):

For reference, GeoJSON is officially supported in Mongoose 3.6

[See the release notes here](https://github.com/LearnBoost/mongoose/wiki/3.6-Release-Notes#geojson-support-mongodb--24).

Example (from the docs):

```
new Schema({ loc: { type: [Number], index: '2dsphere'}})
```

... then ...

```
var geojsonPoly = { type: 'Polygon', coordinates: [[[-5,-5], ['-5',5], [5,5], [5,-5],[-5,'-5']]] }

Model.find({ loc: { $within: { $geometry: geojsonPoly }}})
// or
Model.where('loc').within.geometry(geojsonPoly)
```

Comment: How do you save GeoJson Point using this Scheme ?

Comment: You simply set the value of the `loc` path to an array like this: `item.loc = [lng, lat]; item.save()`

Comment: Thanks, But how a type is defined? Like if I need to define a Polygon or Line or Multi Point ?

Comment: It has to be `Model.where('loc').within()...`.

Answer (score 5):

The [mongoose-geojson-schema](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mongoose-geojson-schema) package was created to make it easy to have GeoJSON in Mongoose Schemas.

Answer (score 5):

Mongoose now [officially supports this](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/guide.html#typeKey).

In a nutshell, what you do is, for that schema, you use the `typeKey` setting to tell mongoose to use a different key for type information. Here is an example:

```
var schema = new Schema({
  // Mongoose interpets this as 'loc is an object with 2 keys, type and coordinates'
  loc: { type: String, coordinates: [Number] },
  // Mongoose interprets this as 'name is a String'
  name: { $type: String }
}, { typeKey: '$type' }); // A '$type' key means this object is a type declaration
```

So now instead of declaring type info with the `type` property, you use `$type`. This works at the schema level so use it in the schemas that need it.

Comment: did you try `$where` in the query?
https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/where/

Answer (score 4):

I'm about to start moving all my location references in my MongoDB from `'2d'` to GeoJSON, so I'll encounter the same problem.

- Regarding the `type` problem, you have to follow what I did below to get it working. Mongoose correctly recognises it as a string.
- Nested arrays; I agree that `mongoose.Schema.Types.Mixed` will work, but I think you can try what I did below, let me know if it works. I'm not near a PC with mongo installed to try the schema out.

Here's how I'd define the schema. The nested array can be tweaked to work, so let me know if it doesn't.

```
var LocationObject = new Schema ({
  'type': {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    enum: ['Point', 'LineString', 'Polygon'],
    default: 'Point'
  },
  coordinates: [
    [
      { type: [ Number ]
    ]
  ]
});
```

If you get undesired results in the nesting of the `Array`, try this out instead. Basically nesting in deeper.

```
coordinates: [
  { type: [
    { type: [ Number ] }
  ] }
]
```